# When using the @w3ui/react-uploader why don't the files show up in my account?

Tags: ipfs, web3storage

I'm trying to extend the demo app at https://github.com/web3-storage/w3ui/tree/main/examples/react/file-upload but I'm getting confused on a more general point as I start out.

The demo uses the [@w3ui/react-uploader](https://github.com/web3-storage/w3ui/blob/main/docs/react-uploader.md) component which also relies on the `AuthProvider` from [@w3ui/react-keyring](https://github.com/web3-storage/w3ui/blob/main/docs/react-keyring.md). And I can use the example code to authorize with an email address and then I can upload a file which apparently works and gives me a link/CID to the file I uploaded.

But the file uploads from the example app don't show up in my web3.storage user account associated with the email address I'm using to authorize on the sample code!

Is the missing files just a localhost effect or am I misunderstanding how the w3ui components interact with the service login? Why isn't the uploads list the same between the w3ui examples and the main w3.storage site?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking. The answer simple and not really that technical. For now, the w3up beta API uploads are going into the new system, and the account website isn't connected to it yet. As we come out of beta we'll move all the existing data to the new system, and update the website to reference the combined datasets.

To list your uploads now, you can use the [UploadsList component of w3ui](https://beta.ui.web3.storage/uploads-table), running in the same app you uploaded from. In the future [w3console](https://github.com/web3-storage/w3console) will be able to show you all your uploads across all apps.

The data will be merged based on the email address of the account that created it, so if you create multiple spaces in your use of beta w3up and w3ui APIs, all that data will be visible from one screen on the website. This will also have any uploads made to the existing API on the main site.

If you are using w3up beta with NFT data, and want your account moved to NFT.Storage, there will be a process for that. It will be easier if you use one email address for all your NFT spaces, and another for any web3.storage spaces.